# C: Reverse individual words in a string

Tags: c, strings

I have been practicing C and I wanted to reverse each word in a string. I wrote this code and although it works, I am not happy with my solution. It requires **twice** the length of the original string to store the `result` and `buffer` respectively and there are **too many if statements** which makes the code hacky. I am wondering how can I do better?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* str = "123 456 789";

    int i, j = 0, k, l = 0;
    int str_len = (int)strlen(str);
    char buffer[str_len];
    int buffer_size = 0;
    char result[str_len + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];

        if (c == ' ' || (i + 1) == str_len)
        {
            short is_end_of_string = 0;
            if ((i + 1) == str_len)
            {
                buffer_size++;
                buffer[l] = c;
                is_end_of_string = 1;
            }

            for (k = 0; k < buffer_size / 2; k++)
            {
                char temp = buffer[k];
                buffer[k] = buffer[buffer_size - k - 1];
                buffer[buffer_size - k - 1] = temp;
            }

            for (k = 0; k < buffer_size; k++)
            {
                result[j++] = buffer[k];
            }

            if (!is_end_of_string)
            {
                result[j++] = c;
                buffer_size = 0;
                l = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buffer_size++;
            buffer[l++] = c;
        }
    }
    result[j] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/LgbwjmCN7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Clarify "word"**

OP's "word" seems to be characters separated by a space `' '`.  A more common definition would use any white-space (tabs, end-of-line, etc.) , not just `' '` as a separator.

Research `isspace()` in `<ctype.h>`.

**Alternative**

> It requires twice the length of the original string

No need to find the string or word length anywhere.  O(1) extra memory needed, unlike OP's O(length) for an in-place reversal.

Algorithm:

```
p = string start

forever    
  while is white-space: p++
  if p[0] then
    note beginning address
    while p[0] and is non-white-space: p++
    note one-past-end-of-word address
    while one-past-end-of-word > beginning
      swap (beginning[0], one-past-end-of-word[-1])
      beginning++;
      one-past-end-of-word--;
  else we are done
```

**For general use: String length may exceed `INT_MAX`**

Use `size_t` to handle all possible *string* lengths.  Cast not needed.  Note that `size_t` is an *unsigned* type, so other parts of code made need changing too.

```
// int str_len = (int)strlen(str);
size_t str_len = strlen(str);
```

**For *boolean* objects, use `_Bool` or `bool`**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// short is_end_of_string = 0;
bool is_end_of_string = false;

// is_end_of_string = 1;
is_end_of_string = true;
```

There are times to use maybe `unsigned char` for a boolean if we had a *large* array of booleans, yet this is not the case here.

**Testing**

Try more challenging strings too.

```
"123 456 789"
" 123 456 789"
"123 456 789 "
" 123 456 789  "
"123\t 456\n 789"
" "
""
"1 2 3\n"
```

**Advanced**

Access characters of a string via `unsigned char *` instead of `char *` for more proper use of `is...()` functions in `<ctype.h>` which can fail with negative values.

Pedantic: `unsigned char *` access also handles rare non-2's complement with *signed char* to properly distinguish between +0 and -0.

**Print with sentinels**

Easier to detect proper handling of leading/trailing white-space.

```
// printf("%s\n", result);
printf("<%s>\n", result);
```